# Does a running Linux write on the SD card it was booting from?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I intend to install a consoled Linux on an SD card. The small computer it will run on, have 128MB memory. There will be a database server and a HTTP server installed, but the data files will be on an SSD or pendrive. I don't want the Linux to write anything on the SD card, it should just read it by booting and running the applications. Is this possible?

Comment: Title doesn't match text. *"Is this possible?"* -- Yes.

Comment: There are numerous featherweight distros that run entirely from RAM and can do so after loading from a CD (which isn't writable), so writing to the SD card is not mandatory.

Comment: @fixer1234 Is Arch or Debian one of those? (the device is pogoplug v4)

Comment: Neither is RAM resident, although there are a number that are based on Debian.  This list will get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM.  Using one of these would involve the least customizing but my point was more to use it as an example that Linux doesn't necessarily require writing to the boot device (or any device).  Probably any distro could be customized in this way if you know what you're doing.  Recognize that nothing from the session would be retained without saving session information somewhere (doesn't need to be the boot device).

Comment: BTW, I've created many "computer on an SD card" using various featherweight distros and have never had a problem booting any of them.  Puppy Linux provides a lot of information on how to set up a save file where you want using Puppy.

Comment: If you are using a USB card reader, you may need to edit the boot configuration (on the card) to include a 5 or 10 second delay before trying to load Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand. are you trying to boot off a SD card and save files to the hard drive? ("im going to try to answer it anyway")

What linux distro? I know on ubuntu you can tell ubuntu where to install, how to install, where to save other files, and even to run without installing! With most Distros, files not OS related will be saved to the hard drive by default.

Ubuntu can be configured/install in pretty much every way imaginable. [Offical Ubuntu Installation Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

Comment: I am not sure whether I can install ubuntu on pogoplug v4. I can install arch, but according to the manual it does not boot from sd card. Another option is debian, which can boot from sd card. That's all I know, so I guess I want to install debian. http://hyperlogos.org/blog/drink/Debian-Pogoplug-V4-Mobile Yes I want to boot from SD card and save files to a pendrive/SSD/HDD. (It does not matter on which.)

Comment: i installed ubuntu from an SD card on me PC, and it worked fine. Also, saving files to the hard drive is default on debain.